# JMeter - Blazemeter recorded scripts - How to remove CSS from the View Results Tree

Tags: css, jmeter, blazemeter

I have recorded the scripts using blazemeter for login module and imported the JMX file into JMeter and run the scripts.

In listener -> View Results Tree-> I have got the output as 404-page not found with the error in CSS file.

How to exclude CSS from the results.

Need to remove the CSS scripts from the result. Where do I need to exclude css scripts without using HTTPS
Test Script Recorder.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Untick this box under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults):

   [image]

   this way JMeter won't fetch so called "embedded resources" like images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. But be aware that real browsers actually do request this content and its "weight" in kilobytes is much more than the main response so I wouldn't discard this
2. Configure JMeter to ignore the failures of the embedded resources by adding the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the change up.